# How to toggle open and close arrows in HTML in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, animation, expandablelistview

I have a long list and want to give it the option of expanding and retracting. Right now, the functionality works, but I don't know how to animate the arrow so that it points up when the page is expanded.

```
  <a id="outline"></a>
  <div
    class="container relative border"
    (click)="this.showOutline = !this.showOutline"
  >
    <h3 class="text-3xl py-4 px-5 text-gray-800">Topic outline</h3>
    <button
      class="absolute bottom-0 border-0 text-2xl z-10 w-full text-center bg-transparent"
    >
      &#8964;
    </button>
    <div class="overflow-hidden">
      <div [innerHtml]="data.outline" [class.collapsed]="!showOutline"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
  max-height: 200px;
}

.collapsed:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 150px, rgb(230, 249, 240));
}
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-upheak?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Ideally, you could drop the code into a online IDE like https://stackblitz.com 
and immediately someone can get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: I added a link to Stackblitz

Comment: It doesn't work fine. It doesn't collapse anything.Can you fix it? If I undertood well, once it works fine, you only need to change the "icon" of the arrow (up<->down), right?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what research you've done, and what you've attempted to solve this yourself. There are hundreds of questions on Stack Overflow about how to animate arrows pointing in one direction to point in the other, for instance.

Comment: So it does work, it's just unfortunately subtle. When you first go to it, you'll see a green hue at the bottom. This matches the page we're using. When you click the arrow, the green gradient goes away, which signifies the content is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this using ngIf. To read more about *ngIf see https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

```
<section>
  <a id="outline"></a>
  <div
    class="container relative border"
    (click)="this.showOutline = !this.showOutline"
 >
<h3 class="text-3xl py-4 px-5 text-gray-800">Topic outline</h3>
<button
  class="
    absolute
    bottom-0
    border-0
    text-2xl
    z-10
    w-full
    text-center
    bg-transparent
  "
>
<span *ngIf="showOutline; else upwardsArrow" >
  &#8964;
</span>
<ng-template #upwardsArrow>
  &#8964; <!-- replace with upwards arrow -->
</ng-template>

  
</button>
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <div [innerHtml]="data.outline" [class.collapsed]="!showOutline"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 'else' doesn't work in the file